# send SMS for 1 time with arduino GPRS SIM900 if an iput is HIGH (4 Digi inputs)

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, c

I faced a problem to send 1 SMS if an input is HIGH,and if it is LOW==> no SMS to send,if LOW to HIGH==> send 1 SMS. this code not working,just sent SMS when I turn the GPRS on,and after nothing is happened.
Thank you for helping in advance.

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 #include "TimerOne.h"

 const int DI = 2;
 const int DT = 3;
 const int DGP1 = 4;
 const int DGP2 = 5;
 const long interval = 100000; // in microseconds

 int value1 = 0;
 int value2 = 0;
 int value3 = 0;
 int value4 = 0;

 int value1_old = 0;
 int value2_old = 0;
 int value3_old = 0;
 int value4_old = 0;

 boolean changed1 = false;
 boolean changed2 = false;
 boolean changed3 = false;
 boolean changed4 = false;

 SoftwareSerial SIM900 (7, 8);

 void SIM900power(){
   digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
   digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   delay(5000);
 }

 void initia(){
   SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
   delay(100);
   SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"xxxxxxxxxx\"");
   delay(100);
  }

 void Send_SMS(){
    SIM900.println((char)26);
    delay(100);
    SIM900.println();
    delay(5000);

  }

  void isr_timer(){
    if (changed2) {
      initia();
      SIM900.println("Station 85: Defaut electrique");
      delay(100);
      Send_SMS();
      value2_old = value2;
      changed2 = false;
   }  

   if (changed3) {
     initia();
     SIM900.println("Station 85: DefautGP1");
     delay(100);
     Send_SMS();
     value3_old = value3;
     changed3 = false;
   }

   if (changed4) {
     initia();
     SIM900.println("Station 85:DD>1000");
     delay(100);
     Send_SMS();
     value4_old = value4;
     changed4 = false;
   }
 }

 void setup() {
    pinMode(DI, INPUT);
    pinMode(DT, INPUT);
    pinMode(DGP1, INPUT);
    pinMode(DGP2, INPUT);

    SIM900.begin(19200);
    Timer1.initialize(interval);
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(isr_timer);
  }

  void loop() {
    value1 = digitalRead (DI);
    value2 = digitalRead (DT);
    value3 = digitalRead (DGP1);
    value4 = digitalRead (DGP2);

    if (value1 != value1_old && value1 == HIGH) changed1 = true;
    if (value2 != value2_old && value2 == HIGH) changed2 = true;
    if (value3 != value3_old && value3 == HIGH) changed3 = true;
    if (value4 != value4_old && value4 == HIGH) changed4 = true;

    value1_old = value1;
    value2_old = value2;
    value3_old = value3;
    value4_old = value4;

  }
```